# After SQL updating Table with ID = min(ID) and a boolean flag, then how to get the updated ID? Without using procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, h2, sql-returning

```
UPDATE id_worker 
SET worker = 'A' 
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM id_worker WHERE worker IS NULL)
```

And then get the id of updated row.

I found MySQL has some `returning` trick. But can this be done in H2 and PostgreSQL without using procedure?

May be add an UUID column and set from caller is a trick? But need space and not elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has the `RETURNING` clause:

```
UPDATE id_worker SET worker = 'A' WHERE id = ...
RETURNING id;
```

[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

Comment: i tried it in h2, this is not working. Any idea for h2?

Comment: Nope, H2 obviously does not have the feature: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#update. (Originally, you wrote Postgres *or* H2.)

Comment: Sorry, i made an logic mistake.. it should be an 'And' not 'Or'. Cross-database between h2 and postgresql is a must. Maybe a function/uuid is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `returning` clause:

```
with w as (
      update id_worker 
         set worker = 'A' 
         where id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM id_worker WHERE worker IS NULL)
         returning *
    )
select *
from w;
```